# Spring Social Facebook | Get big photo from feedOperations

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

When i am executing below code, i am getting only small picture.

```
PagingParameters recordCount = new PagingParameters(2000, null, null, null);
PagedList<Post> posts = facebook.feedOperations().getPosts(recordCount);
```

Maven version:

```
<dependency
<groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId> <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```

How can we get the full picture for feed operation. Is there is any option for this?

Comment: Spring Social Facebook | Get full picture from user post or page.

Answer (score 0):

I analyze a lots and posting solution for this question, since other can take help from this. It return full picture as part of extra data of post that can be fetch using post.getExtraData().get("full_picture"). code snapshot is as below

```
public PagedList<Post> getPostByAccountId(final String accountId) {
    LOGGER.debug("facebook accountId: ", accountId);
    FacebookTemplate facebook = new FacebookTemplate("<access token>");

    String[] ALL_POST_FIELDS = { "id", "actions", "admin_creator", "application", "caption", "created_time", "description", "from", "icon", "is_hidden", "is_published",
            "link", "message", "message_tags", "name", "object_id", "picture", "full_picture", "place", "privacy", "properties", "source", "status_type", "story", "to",
            "type", "updated_time", "with_tags", "shares" };

    URIBuilder uriBuilder = URIBuilder.fromUri(facebook.getBaseGraphApiUrl() + "me/posts");
    uriBuilder = uriBuilder.queryParam("limit", String.valueOf(2000));
    uriBuilder.queryParam("fields", org.springframework.util.StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(ALL_POST_FIELDS));
    URI uri = uriBuilder.build();

    JsonNode jsonNode = (JsonNode) facebook.getRestTemplate().getForObject(uri, JsonNode.class);
    PagedList<Post> posts = new DeserializingPosts().deserializeList(jsonNode, null, Post.class);
    return posts;
}
```

To fetch full_picture from post.

```
String picture = post.getPicture(); 
picture = post.getExtraData().get("full_picture") != null ? post.getExtraData().get("full_picture").toString() : picture;
```

deserializingObject Class details:

```
public class DeserializingPosts extends AbstractOAuth2ApiBinding {

private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

/**
 * 
 * @param jsonNode
 * @param postType
 * @param type
 * @return
 */
public <T> PagedList<T> deserializeList(JsonNode jsonNode, String postType, Class<T> type) {
    JsonNode dataNode = jsonNode.get("data");
    List posts = new ArrayList();
    for (Iterator iterator = dataNode.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        posts.add(deserializePost(postType, type, (ObjectNode) iterator.next()));
    }
    if (jsonNode.has("paging")) {
        JsonNode pagingNode = jsonNode.get("paging");
        PagingParameters previousPage = PagedListUtils.getPagedListParameters(pagingNode, "previous");
        PagingParameters nextPage = PagedListUtils.getPagedListParameters(pagingNode, "next");
        return new PagedList(posts, previousPage, nextPage);
    }

    return new PagedList(posts, null, null);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param postType
 * @param type
 * @param node
 * @return
 */
public <T> T deserializePost(String postType, Class<T> type, ObjectNode node) {
    try {
        if (postType == null) {
            postType = determinePostType(node);
        }

        node.put("postType", postType);
        node.put("type", postType);
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = super.getJsonMessageConverter();
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.objectMapper.registerModule(new FacebookModule());
        converter.setObjectMapper(this.objectMapper);
        return this.objectMapper.reader(type).readValue(node.toString());
    } catch (IOException shouldntHappen) {
        throw new UncategorizedApiException("facebook", "Error deserializing " + postType + " post", shouldntHappen);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param node
 * @return
 */
private String determinePostType(ObjectNode node) {
    if (node.has("type")) {
        try {
            String type = node.get("type").textValue();
            Post.PostType.valueOf(type.toUpperCase());
            return type;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return "post";
        }
    }
    return "post";
}
```

}